# What's the best way to avoid binary rounding errors affecting conditions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I noticed this strange behavior in a part of my code:

```
num = 0.14
num += 0.01

if num == 0.15:
    print('equal')
elif num > 0.15:
    print('greater')
elif num < 0.15:
    print('less')

> greater
```

I assume this is because of binary rounding errors, so `num` is actually stored as `0.1500000000001` or something.
I'm just wondering what is the best way to avoid these kinds of errors in conditional statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course rounding:

```
num = 0.14
num += 0.01
num=round(num,2)
if num == 0.15:
    print('equal')
elif num > 0.15:
    print('greater')
elif num < 0.15:
    print('less')
```

Output:

```
equal
```

Even better `decimal` module:

```
from decimal import Decimal
num = Decimal('0.14')
num += Decimal('0.01')
num=float(num)
if num == 0.15:
    print('equal')
elif num > 0.15:
    print('greater')
elif num < 0.15:
    print('less')
```

Output:

```
equal
```

And of course, compare `decimal.Decimal` types:

```
from decimal import Decimal
num = Decimal('0.14')
num += Decimal('0.01')
if num == Decimal('0.15'):
    print('equal')
elif num > Decimal('0.15'):
    print('greater')
elif num < Decimal('0.15'):
    print('less')
```

Output:

```
equal
```